# Php form instead send mail download on computer

Tags: php, html, css

```
<div class="contact_form clearfix" id="Contact">
    <h2><a href="#header">Hello... You can send me message to my universe here.</a></h2>
    <a href="#header"><img src="img/planeta1.png" alt=""> </a>

    <form class="clearfix spaceForm" action="contactform.php" metod="post" >

            <label for="name">Your name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Jon Doe" required>


            <label for="email">Your email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="something@mama.com" required>



            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required>


            <label for="message">Your message:</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required></textarea>

            <button type="submit" name="submit">Send mail</button>


</div>


and php code here...

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $mailTo = "pisitenam@sammostalnisindikatstark.org.rs";
        $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
        $txt = "You have received an e-mail from " .$name.".\n\n".$message;

        mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
        header("Location: index.html");
    }


?>
```

My contact form instead to send message download on computer as php file. I uploaded my site to netfly but stil doesnt work.

Can anybody help and give me a hint where is problem?

On XAMPP im getting blank page and mail is not sent. When I uploaded site on netfly site works fine but contact from when click submit start download php file where is code writen for controling contact form.5 day im trying to find solution for this problem and im geting tired :D So if anybody can help...

Answer (score 0):

you are having some spell mistake in your form tag, first of all correct the method spell in your code as it is not correct so it can't redirect and post your data to contact form.

Comment: I still have problem. Changed email in form and post mail in php file but still download file instead send a message.

Comment: are you working on core php or using any framework as PHP requires an installed and working email system in case of core php if you are not using any mail library.

Comment: you can use email library to send mail. by using library you can also attach files and improve your mailing fucntionality. for sending mail you need a mailing server which can set using library.

Comment: this is pure php code .. im not using framework. still noob for php. Idea was to receive mails from my web page via contact form. email library is new for me. :(

Comment: for sending mail you need smtp and port for sending mail as our browser send mail using smtp port which denotes simple mail transfer protocol without any protocol you can not send mail. you can use your smtp server or google smtp server for testing mail sending.

Answer (score 0):

mail library contains various function.
for example:

```
<?php require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'your_smtp_domain.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';           // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                   // TCP port to connect to
$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('john@example.net', 'John doe'); // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);                              // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

this can works for you if you use library.